# Residue integral in the context of PNT

Tags: analytic-number-theory, complex-integration

I need to find the following limiting value:
$$lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT} \frac{a^s}{s}ds$$ where $s \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$

This came up in the context of trying to understand the distribution of primes with respect to the zeros of the Riemann Zeta Function. You might find some printing mistakes, but you may refer to 'A History of PNT' by LJ Goldstein for the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: $a \ge 0$ (for other $a$ it diverges). It depends if you prefer the residue theorem or Fourier analysis. Both give the answer $2i\pi \ 1_{a > 1}$ (at the discontinuity point it is the mean value $1/2$)

Comment: Would you please elaborate, I can't quite see it.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3490586/276986) proof mean something to you ($1/s$ is the Laplace transform of $1_{t > 0}$) ? Otherwise do you know what is $Res(a^s/s,0)$ ?

Comment: I do know that residue is calculated over a simple closed contour

Comment: Also, the integral along a contour with $0$ within it will give $Res(a^s/s,0)$=$2\pi i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_T$ be the rectangle $[-T,2]+i[-T,T]$. Then for $a > 1$ $$\lim_{T\to \infty} \frac1{2i\pi}\int_{\partial \ C_T} \frac{a^s}{s}ds=lim_{T\to\infty}\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{2-iT}^{2+iT} \frac{a^s}{s}ds$$
On the other hand $$\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{\partial \ C_T} \frac{a^s}{s}ds=Res(\frac{a^s}{s},0)=1$$
For $a \in (0,1)$ it is the same with the rectangle $R_T=[2,T]+i[-T,T]$, it contains no pole thus $\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{\partial \ R_T} \frac{a^s}{s}ds=0$.

> This way we have proven the Mellin inversion theorem for $1_{x > 1}$

Comment: How is the contour chosen for integration?

Comment: $\partial \ C_T$ is the boundary of a rectangle

Comment: That is certainly understood, but how are the rectangles chosen with respect to the variation of values of $a$?

Comment: Was looking for the reason for choosing different contours for these kinds of integrals. Would be obliged if answered.

Comment: It is because for $a >1$, $a^s$ is rapidly decreasing as $\Re(s)\to - \infty$ whereas for $a \in (0,1)$ it is as $\Re(s)\to \infty$