# Book Recommendation for Proving Inverse Laplace Transform using Fourier Transform

Tags: book-recommendation, advice

What is your recommendation to understand proof of Inverse Laplace Transform using Fourier Transform in detail?

By the way i found one book that talked about it from *Mathematical Methods for Physicists by Arfken, Weber, and Harris*, unfortunately this book just skips many steps on the proof and this just makes me confuse.

So, i've seen some similar questions:

- [Similar question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490539/can-someone-provide-a-derivation-of-the-laplace-inversion-formula)
- [Similar question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2926685)

Sadly they didn't discussed about book recommendation. And actually i want to cite it (the proof) that's why i need to understand the full proof, so i just need the book recommendation for a convenient reason. Hope you can help me to find book or journal that discuss about it.

Thanks in advance!